# Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on java.util.Deque.push

Tags: java, android, exception, svg, queue

It's really strange, Google Developer Console, error reporting page.

As it seems, my application crashes on several Android devices. The exception log provided says:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Deque.push
at com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser$SVGHandler.<init>(SVGParser.java:869)
at com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGBuilder.build(SVGBuilder.java:147)
at myapp.graphic.PictureCache.getSvgPicture(PictureCache.java:59)
at myapp.graphic.PictureCache.getSvgPictureDrawable(PictureCache.java:65)
at myapp.activities.startup.ActivityStartup.setupCustomGraphic(ActivityStartup.java:92)
at myapp.activities.startup.ActivityStartup.onCreate(ActivityStartup.java:35)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
...
```

I'm using that library:

http://code.google.com/p/svg-android-2/

I included the source cod, not simply linked the external library.

The code seems to fail on `java.util.Deque.push` (**NoSuchMethodError**). It's not a problem of the source code I've copied and pasted, it seems that no dequeue method is found on runtime! How it's possible? Can't imagine.

**EDIT:**
The Deque is define:

```
Deque<Matrix> matrixStack = new LinkedList<Matrix>();
```

The code that raise the problem:

```
matrixStack.push(new Matrix());
```

Is it possible that `new Matrix()` returns a value that is not accepted by the `push()` method?

Comment: check if you have updated adt to rev 22? if so right click on your project java build path choose order export tab make sure you have checked android private libraries for both your project and android project. This is only a suggestion.

Comment: It looks like java.util.Deque.push is introduced in Java.6 , and may not be available in older versions. I suggest you to check the runt-time environment in the devices where application fails.

Comment: @scubadiver But wait...`Deque` wasn't even present in Java 5, so it should fail with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Deque` on versions older than Java 6. Maybe the Android library is Java 6 or 7 but does not contain the `push` method.

Comment: I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project references `java.util.Deque` which was only added in API level 9

(http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Deque.html)

Devices with API level < 9 will fail as they cannot call this Class/method as it doesn't exist on them.

Comment: I've android:minSdkVersion="8" and android:minSdkVersion="8" in my manifest.xml and I get no compile error/warning (I use Android 2.3.3 libraries) !

Comment: Deque also exists in your JDK (since 1.6), which is why it's probably not warning you. At runtime though, on devices < 9, it will fail. I am not an expert on how the warnings work. I am pretty confident this is your problem though. Have you tested on a device with API level < 9?

Comment: The problem arises because I uses Android 2.3.3 (Api 9) library when  android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8". Solved, after the contribute from Ken by setting  android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="9".