# Java Build Path, Order and Export: should I include Android libraries?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compilation

I'm little confused about project properties, Java Build Path, Order and Export when compiling an Android project.

Look at this:

[image]

Should I check **Android 2.3.3**, **Android Dependencies** and **android.jar** ?

when compiling my android project to be sure that everything will works fine on the destination device. My doubts arise because **I get an error on some devices**, please look at my previous question:

[Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on java.util.Deque.push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988593/exception-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-on-java-util-deque-push)

Comment: give it a try and check

Comment: It's dangerous to publish a new version on the market just to give it a try. Unfortunatelly the problem arises only with some devices. I do not have one of these devices so I can't try before pubblication.

Comment: Have you updated ADT recently? Make sure your plugin and SDK tools and SDK build-tools are up to date.

Comment: Do the "some devices" have anything in common? Platform/hardware version, etc?

Comment: Devices reported as "OTHER" by the Developer Console...

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to your exporting. Your project references `java.util.Deque` which was only added in API level 9

(http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Deque.html)

Devices with API level < 9 will fail as they cannot call this Class/method as it doesn't exist on them.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting! But I've android:minSdkVersion="8" and android:minSdkVersion="8" in my manifest.xml and I get **no compile error/warning** (I use Android 2.3.3 libraries) !

Comment: I'm not an expert on how and why it should warn you. Do you explitly reference Deque in your code?